# Guerroyer, batailler, se battre, combattre, lutter : différences

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, synonymes

Quelle est la différence entre ces verbes lors d'un emploi métaphorique ? P.ex.

> Macron s'est battu/ a combattu/ a lutté/ a guerroyé/ a bataillé pour le pass vaccinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est sûrement un peu subjectif, un peu *opinion based* mais voici les différences qu'on peut percevoir :

- **s'est battu** : valorisant pour celui qui se bat, c'est celui que je choisirais.
- **a combattu** : suppose un combat, met l'accent sur l'adversaire.
- **a lutté** : sous-entend plus que les autres verbes qu'il a souffert, qu'il a peut-être perdu.
- **a guerroyé**<sup>1</sup> : assez moqueur, dévalorise la personne qui se bat.
- **a bataillé** : sous-entend qu'il y a eu plusieurs batailles, que ça n'a pas été facile, mon deuxième choix ici.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Le Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/guerroyer) (1863) écrit déjà: *Terme familier dans le langage moderne ; il était du style élevé dans le langage ancien.* Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guerroyer) ajoute cette remarque : *S'emploie souvent de nos jours avec une nuance ironique.*</sub>

Comment: On peut noter que guerroyer peut être perçu comme moqueur car vieilli, désuet.

Comment: @XouDo C'est vrai, j'ai rajouté ce point à ma réponse, merci.